# Detect mouse dragging on QGraphicsItems Qt

Tags: qt, events, qgraphicsitem

Well, I have such problem.
I have several custom QGraphicsItems on scene. They are not movable. When I press on one of them and move mouse, I want the others to change their color when pressed mouse enters them, but they don't do it. I have tried a lot, but everything ended in failure. Is there a way to solve my problem?
I'm grateful for every advice.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Did you use QGraphicsItems::mouseMoveEvent() ?